# how to use phpmyadmin in fedora?

Tags: fedora, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpmyadmin using yum command. mysql, apache, php were already installed.
Now when I go to htpp://localhost/phpmyadmin in the web browser, I get a window asking me for a username and password preceded by the following message:

```
A username and password are being requested by http://localhost. The site says: "phpMyAdmin localhost"
```

I am clueless what is happening here. Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I would expect phpMyAdmin to request a MySQL username and password. The MySQL root user can (and should) have a different password from the normal root password.

You did secure your MySQL install with a password, right?

Comment: thanks buddy.. wasted whole day figuring out what was wrong.. I ran /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation and set a password different than the root password, user id remains same =  root.. and it worked beautifully!